# How to preserve hyperlinks in Joomla4 when using enqueueMessage()?

Tags: joomla-4, modal

How can I add a hyperlink in an error message in Joomla4?

I used hyperlinks in enqueueMessage text in joomla 3.x without any problems.

Now I'm using Joomla 4.x and it removes the hyperlink -- it removes the  `href=*` part inside the html tag.

```
JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(
    'Something is wrong <a href = \'/index.php?option=com_hccxmlbeheer&view=nieuwaccount\'>klik to fix</a>'
);
```

Generates:

```
Something is wrong <a>klik to fix</a>
```

How can I stop `enqueueMessage()` stripping the `href` attribute from my html text?

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me in J3. Filter doesn't handle spaces around attributes well. You should report the issue to Filter repository https://github.com/joomla-framework/filter. In the meantime you can remove the spaces from your code.